# How get the non visible view from the ListView of EditTexts and retain the changes made to the EditText in android?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-edittext, android-adapter

I am struck with one problem. I have a ListView of EditTexts (of 6 columns).
I have save button/. On saving the, I want all the text present in the each of the EditTexts(even if changes made to them). I am getting the null View if the view is non visible. And the changes made to the EditText is not retained on scrolling(it is resetting to old value). The following is the code. 
Adapter class

```
private class MyPrescriptionsAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener{

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private  LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    View vi;
    int position;
    Typeface fontFields;
    public MyPrescriptionsAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data = d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final Holder holder;
        this.position=position;
       // tviewStrength.requestFocus();


        if (convertView == null){
            holder=new Holder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myprescriptions_adapter, null);
            holder.tviewMedicine = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tview_medicine);
            holder.tviewStrength = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tview_strenth);
            holder.tviewUnit = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edtxt_strenthunit);
            holder.tviewQty = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tview_qty);
            holder.tviewFrequency = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tview_frequency);
            holder.tviewMode = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tview_mode);
            holder.tviewEndDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tview_enddate);
            holder.tviewFreqId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tview_freqId);
            holder.tviewModeId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tview_modeId);
            holder.tviewDrugId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tview_unitId);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder= (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        fontFields = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity
                .getAssets(), activity.getResources().getString(R.string.font_RobotoLightItalic));
        holder.tviewMedicine.setTypeface(fontFields);
        holder.tviewStrength.setTypeface(fontFields);
        holder.tviewQty.setTypeface(fontFields);
        holder.tviewFrequency.setTypeface(fontFields);
        holder.tviewMode.setTypeface(fontFields);
        holder.tviewEndDate.setTypeface(fontFields);

        final HashMap<String, String> listMedication;
        listMedication = data.get(position);

        // Setting all values in listview

        holder.tviewMedicine.setText(listMedication.get("medicine_name"));
        holder.tviewStrength.setText(listMedication.get(activity.getString(R.string.tag_Strength)));
        holder.tviewQty.setText(listMedication.get(activity.getString(R.string.tag_Quantity)));
        holder.tviewFrequency.setText(listMedication.get(activity.getString(R.string.tag_frequency)));
        holder.tviewMode.setText(listMedication.get(activity.getString(R.string.tag_mode)));
        holder.tviewUnit.setText(listMedication.get(activity.getString(R.string.tag_unitname)));
        holder.tviewEndDate.setText(listMedication.get(activity.getString(R.string.tag_EndDate)));
        holder.tviewModeId.setText(listMedication.get(activity.getString(R.string.tag_AdminMode)));
        holder.tviewFreqId.setText(listMedication.get(activity.getString(R.string.tag_Frequency)));
        holder.tviewDrugId.setText(listMedication.get(activity.getString(R.string.tag_Drugid)));

        holder.tviewFrequency.setOnClickListener(this);
        holder.tviewMode.setOnClickListener(this);
        holder.tviewUnit.setOnClickListener(this);
        holder.tviewQty.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                View childView = listviewMeditation.getFocusedChild();
                if (childView != null) {
                    TextView edEndDate = (TextView) childView.findViewById(R.id.tview_enddate);
                    EditText edFreq = (EditText) childView.findViewById(R.id.tview_frequency);
                    setEndDate(edEndDate, edFreq.getText().toString(), holder.tviewQty.getText().toString());
                }
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
    private class Holder{
        TextView tviewMedicine;
        EditText tviewStrength;
        EditText tviewQty;
        EditText tviewFrequency;
        EditText tviewMode;
        TextView tviewEndDate;
        EditText tviewUnit;
        TextView tviewFreqId;
        TextView tviewModeId;
        TextView tviewDrugId;
    }
```

Here, below I am accessing the all the required EditText's text.

```
 public  void getData() {
   int countChild= listviewMeditation.getCount();
    HashMap<String,String>mapEdValues;
    EditText edStrenghth;
    EditText edQty;
    EditText edFrequency;
    EditText edMode;
    EditText edUnit;
    TextView edMedicine,edEndate,tvDrugId,tvModeId,tvFreqId;


    if (countChild>0){
        for (int i=0;i<countChild;i++){
            mapEdValues=new HashMap<>();
            view=listviewMeditation.getChildAt(i); // here i am getting null view
            edStrenghth = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.tview_strenth);
            edQty = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.tview_qty);
            edUnit = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edtxt_strenthunit);
            edEndate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tview_enddate);
            tvDrugId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tview_unitId);
            tvFreqId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tview_freqId);
            tvModeId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tview_modeId);

            mapEdValues.put("added", String.valueOf(addCount));
            mapEdValues.put(getString(R.string.tag_Strength), edStrenghth.getText().toString());
            mapEdValues.put(getString(R.string.tag_Quantity), edQty.getText().toString());
            mapEdValues.put(getString(R.string.tag_EndDate), edEndate.getText().toString());
            mapEdValues.put(getString(R.string.tag_unitname), edUnit.getText().toString());
            mapEdValues.put(getString(R.string.tag_Frequency), tvFreqId.getText().toString());
            mapEdValues.put(getString(R.string.tag_AdminMode), tvModeId.getText().toString());
            mapEdValues.put(getString(R.string.tag_DrugId), tvDrugId.getText().toString());
            mapEdValues.put(getString(R.string.tag_DrugGroupId), "0");
            editedMedication.add(mapEdValues);
        }

    }

}
```

Any help...........

Comment: public View getViewByPosition(int position, ListView listView) {
        final int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + listView.getChildCount() - 1;

        if (position < firstListItemPosition || position > lastListItemPosition ) {
            return listView.getAdapter().getView(position, listView.getChildAt(position), listView);
        } else {
            final int childIndex = position - firstListItemPosition;
            return listView.getChildAt(childIndex);
        }}

Comment: I tried above.. Now i don't get null. But I'm unable to retain changes made to the EditText

Comment: I think you haven't understood how a ListView works. It's only to display data, once you scroll you lost what was displayed. There is no such thing like an "invisible" View. So if you want to change something in the data displayed you need to store them immediately. And then when the user presses the "save" button, you can save these stored data somewhere else.

Comment: yes.. I have understood the ListView now after referring some sources. Yes I have to try out which u suggested. Thanks for ur suggestion.

Comment: And do u have any idea how to save all the data(modified + non modified) separately for further processing. If u have any plz share